# Firebase .onAuthStateChanged is not returning username on Google/Facebook logins via redirects, but works with email login

Tags: javascript, redirect, oauth, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

```
  firebaseUI.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
    signInFlow: 'redirect',
    signInSuccessUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    signInOptions: [
      firebaseDB.firebase_.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebaseDB.firebase_.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebaseDB.firebase_.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
  });

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      console.log(user.displayName);
    } else {
      console.log('no user signed in');
    }
  });
```

When I use email signing method, the 'user' variable returns properly, but when I sign in via Google or Facebook redirects, I get null for the 'user' variable. However, if I use 'signInFlow' as 'popup' then without the refreshing of the page I get the proper logged in user.displayName variable. Is there a way I can stick with redirect signinflow and still get the proper login credentials to return?

Comment: `user` will only be null in the onAuthStateChanged callback when the user is definitely signed out.  Without more debugging information, it's hard to know why that is.

Comment: oic, ya I checked by changing the signInSuccessUrl to something else and indeed it doesn't seem to work when I try to sign in with Google or Facebook, so I gotta fix that first, thanks.

Comment: What's the proper way of debugging firebase login processes? When I click on google login, it goes to the correct sign-in page that shows the correct firebase database app it is connecting to, yet when I click on my google account and redirect back to the login screen, nothing has happened other than my console logs notifying my I haven't yet logged in.

Comment: I checked the users in the firebase database console, and each time I log in with one my dummy google accounts, it does register there, so it's just no registering on my front-end...